# SAP BTP Portal - App react Not found after refresh(F5)

Tags: reactjs, sap-business-technology-platform

Run HTML5 Aplication with ReactJS in SAP BTP Portal or Launchapd service. However when the page is reloaded or an external link is used for an internal route of the application it ends up giving the error 404. It seems to me that the approuter is not prepared for this. How could an external link work and lead to the app's internal route?

xs-app.json

```
{
"welcomeFile": "index.html",
"authenticationMethod": "route",
"logout": {
    "logoutEndpoint": "/do/logout",
"logoutPage": "/logout-page.html"
},
"routes": [
 {
  "source": "^/user-api(.*)",
  "target": "$1",
  "service": "sap-approuter-userapi"
 },
 {
  "source": "/api/(.*)$",
  "target": "/api/$1",
  "authenticationType": "xsuaa",     
  "destination": "target-mngt-api",
  "scope": ["$XSAPPNAME.PartnerSales"],
  "csrfProtection": false
},

{
  "source": "/sap/(.*)$",
  "target": "/sap/$1",
  "authenticationType": "xsuaa",     
  "destination": "S4",      
  "csrfProtection": false
 },
 {
  "source": "^/logout-page.html$",
  "service": "html5-apps-repo-rt",
  "authenticationType": "none"
 },
 {
  "source": "^(.*)$",
  "target": "$1",
  "service": "html5-apps-repo-rt",
  "authenticationType": "xsuaa"
 },
{
  "source": "^index.html$",
  "service": "html5-apps-repo-rt",
  "authenticationType": "xsuaa",
  "cacheControl": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    }
  ]
}
```

Starting app
[image: starting app]

navigate to details
[image: navigate to details]

Press F5(refresh)
[image: Press F5(refresh)]

Answer (score 0):

After you build the react app. Create a new file in public folder with a name Staticfile and place the beow content in it.
pushstate: enabled

Then deploy the app to cloudfoundry BTP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking for a more detailed solution.
The answer from Sampathkumar R is correct and works well. Maybe not precise enough to understand.

Here are some hints for you, if you have a similar solution.

1. Seperate the approuter and the web app into two different apps
2. Let the web app use the staticfile buildpack
3. Add the Staticfile file with the content “pushstate: enabled” in the root folder of the buildpack
4. configure the approuter to forward the request to the static app.